# Dynamic Date As Column Name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

On my select statement, I want to call to one of my columns as a dynamic date.

For example, something like:

```
SELECT <column_name> as CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1)
FROM <table_name>
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) AS <column_name>
FROM <table_name>` . Of course change the placeholder coulmn and table names to originals.

Comment: Chanukya, thank you for your answer. I'm afraid you didn't understand my problem.

I wanted the dynamic date to be the column's name and not the record's value.

Comment: Then you could explain more, why you need a date as column name and provide some input data, expected result?

Comment: Imagine a matrix where there are 8 columns: 8 days ago, 7 days ago... 1 day ago. On the current state, I call them just like this ("8 days ago", "7 days ago"...) but I want to present the date itself instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check dynamic query like below

```
declare  @ssql nvarchar(500)
set @ssql= N'Select Getdate() as ['+ Cast(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) as nvarchar(25))+'] ;'
exec sp_executesql @ssql
```

You can change the select with your column and table name

```
 declare  @ssql nvarchar(500)
 set @ssql= N'Select <colName> as ['+  Cast(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) as nvarchar(25))+'] from tableName ;'  
exec sp_executesql @ssql
```

For additional columns:

```
declare  @ssql nvarchar(500)
 set @ssql= N'Select <colName> as ['+  Cast(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) as nvarchar(25))+'],<colName2> as ['+  Cast(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 2) as nvarchar(25))+']
 ,<colName3> as ['+  Cast(CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 3) as nvarchar(25))+'] from tableName ;'  
exec sp_executesql @ssql
```

Comment: That's a progress! But if I want it to be a matrix (couple of columns and not only one)?

Comment: That's why you need some sample data @Itay Nagar. No one can imagine what you want

Answer (score 0):

Why not storing data with fixed column name "DATE" ? and using simple WHERE date=CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1) ?

Comment: Because the full query should return a matrix, something like:

                  <n days ago> <n-1 days ago> ... <1 day ago>
<group 1>
<group 2>
...
<group n>